# How to call Broadcast Receiver of AAR library inside any project?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, aar

I have created an AAR library, which consist of all classes, methods, Services and Broadcast Receiver. I am using this AAR library in my new project in order to access it's classes which consist of different methods. I am able to access all my classes but i am unable to access Broadcast receiver directly in my project.
I don't know whether that is possible? if it is possible how to do that.
I have set proguard as true in my library,tell me in case that making problem in accessing Broadcast Receiver.
I tried to declare receiver directly in my project manifest but it doesn't work for me.

So how i can use broadcast receiver of external AAR file in my project?

Comment: You need to register the Broadcast Receiver in your Own Manifest.

Comment: i have tried doing that, as all my broadcast receiver are inside AAR library, i am unable to access those receiver in my manifest file.

Comment: Unable to access on Manifest? Its just a string. `ex: android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"`

Comment: i have tried doing that <receiver android:name="com.example.blelib.receiver.IncomingCallReceiver" > but as it is seperate aar library i am unable to access that library's Receiver. don't know whether proguard making any problem.

Comment: Yeah proguard can also be an issue specially when it deals with reflections.

Comment: @SuhasGawde have you found any solution regarding this?